# Pattern Fill for Line Markers (VBA)

Tags: vba, line, series, fill

am trying to copy the pattern fill of line markers from one series to another.
My research indicates that this area of the object model is not very well developed but am still hoping for a solution.

Two things would be helpful for

1. Checking if markers have pattern fill (kind of a "FillTpye" simliar to "ChartType")
2. Copying  the pattern fill from one series to another

This is what I got. It throws an error in the last line.

```
Sub Copy_Marker_Pattern_Fill()

  Dim sSrs As Excel.Series
  Dim tSrs As Excel.Series
  Set sSrs = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
  Set tSrs = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2)

  'Line
  If sSrs.Format.Line.Visible = True Then
    With tSrs.Format.Line
      .Visible = msoFalse
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .Style = sSrs.Format.Line.Style
      .DashStyle = sSrs.Format.Line.DashStyle
      .Weight = sSrs.Format.Line.Weight
      .ForeColor = sSrs.Format.Line.ForeColor
      .ForeColor.TintAndShade = sSrs.Format.Line.ForeColor.TintAndShade
      .ForeColor.Brightness = sSrs.Format.Line.ForeColor.Brightness
    End With
  Else
    tSrs.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
  End If
  
  'Marker
  If sSrs.MarkerStyle <> xlMarkerStyleNone Then
    tSrs.MarkerStyle = sSrs.MarkerStyle
    tSrs.MarkerSize = sSrs.MarkerSize
    tSrs.MarkerBackgroundColor = sSrs.MarkerBackgroundColor 'fill color
    tSrs.MarkerForegroundColor = sSrs.MarkerForegroundColor 'border line color
    tSrs.Format.Fill.Patterned sSrs.Format.Fill.Pattern
  End If

End Sub
```